# Write this equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to write this equation in latex:

[image]

I need that comments be in right side.

I did something like this but it has some flaws.

```
   \begin{eqnarray}
\label{cons1}
  % \begin{aligned}
x_i+w_{mi}\le X_j   \hfill \hfill\text{if i is to the left of j}\\
\label{cons2}
x_i-w_{mj}\ge X_j   \hfill \hfill\text{if i is to the right of j}\\
\label{cons3}
y_i+h_{mi}\le y_j   \hfill \hfill\text{if i is below of j}\\
\label{cons4}
y_i-h_{mj}\ge y_j    \hfill \hfill\text{if i is above of j}
%\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would probably want to use an `align` environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{cons1}
x_i+w_{mi}&\le X_j   &&\text{if $i$ is to the left of $j$}\\
\label{cons2}
x_i-w_{mj}&\ge X_j   &&\text{if $i$ is to the right of $j$}\\
\label{cons3}
y_i+h_{mi}&\le y_j   &&\text{if $i$ is below of $j$}\\
\label{cons4}
y_i-h_{mj}&\ge y_j   &&\text{if $i$ is above of $j$}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You shouldn't use `eqnarray` in LaTeX, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/27635)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `alignat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \label{cons1}
    &x_i+w_{mi}\le X_j   & \qquad & \text{if $i$ is to the left of $j$}\\
    \label{cons2}
    &x_i-w_{mj}\ge X_j   &        & \text{if $i$ is to the right of $j$}\\
    \label{cons3}
    &y_i+h_{mi}\le y_j   &        & \text{if $i$ is below of $j$}\\
    \label{cons4}
    &y_i-h_{mj}\ge y_j    &       & \text{if $i$ is above of $j$}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This info is also very helpful